# SciPy/pytest: Skip specific test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, scipy, pytest

I test my SciPy installation using

```
python -c "import scipy; scipy.test('full', verbose=2)"
```

A single test (test_face) fails, while all other either passes or xfails. This one test fails because the dependency bz2 is lacking, which is fine. How can I specify that I want to skip this test entirely, while still running all other tests?

I'm using SciPy 1.2.0 with pytest 4.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution using the `extra_argv` argument which passes the arguments on to pytest. From the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html), `-k "not test_face"` may be used to skip exactly this test. In total then,

```
python -c "import scipy; scipy.test('full', verbose=2, extra_argv=['-k not test_face'])"
```

achieves what I wanted.